# DbFunctions.TruncateTime() still producing "type member 'Date' is not supported" error

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-6

I'm really having trouble with the LINQ query below. I did a lot of research on this error and almost everything i have found references the use of DbFunctions.TruncateTime(), however this still does not seem to be working for me. I'm hoping someone can take a look at this and let me know where i am going wrong. All i am trying to do is compare only the date portion of the datetime but i continue to get the Exception: **The specified type member 'Date' is not supported in LINQ to Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties are supported.**

```
if (!db.MaintenanceWindows.Any(x => x.Id == Id & 
DbFunctions.TruncateTime(x.BlockedDay) == DateTime.UtcNow.Date & 
x.IsDeleted.Value == false))
{
...
}
```

TIA

Comment: How about `Date` property here `DateTime.UtcNow.Date`

Comment: Yes, what about it? Is it not OK for it to be there?

Comment: I meant, it's using `Date` property - exactly what exception message is telling you :) Why don't you put it into variable outside the query.

Comment: Thanks guys, that solved my issue. Could you kindly elaborate as to why EF doesn't allow this?

Comment: Because it can't be translated into a sql query, it is not a supported canonical function. For every call that you want to support someone has to write code to make sure it can be translated.

Comment: Thanks again for the speedy response. You guys rock!

Comment: Welll, taking into account that `TruncateTime` is the db equivalent of the `DateTime.Date` property, I see no special reason for EF not supporting it. They just didn't :)

Comment: Feel free to throw the answer up for some points...

Answer (score 0):

It's not complaining about the `DbFunctions.TruncateTime`. It's complaining about the  `DateTime.UtcNow.Date`

Suggestion A:
*(not recommended)*

```
if (!db.MaintenanceWindows.Any(x => x.Id == Id && 
    DbFunctions.TruncateTime(x.BlockedDay) == DbFunctions.TruncateTime(DateTime.UtcNow) && 
    x.IsDeleted.Value == false))
```

Suggestion B:

```
var utcNow = DateTime.UtcNow.Date;
if (!db.MaintenanceWindows.Any(x => x.Id == Id && 
    DbFunctions.TruncateTime(x.BlockedDay) == utcNow && 
    x.IsDeleted.Value == false))
```

Also, you are going to want the "logical AND"  (`&&`) in the expression.

Comment: I do not recommend suggestion A. This way the SQL server must for every record truncate time from declared variable.
Best way to have fast SQL queries is to have all possible parameters static.

Comment: Suggestion A is the closest to his original code, and B is the optimized version.  I should have made that clear.